# Attempting To Make A Python Program That Replaces Consonant Words With "?" Based Off User Input

Tags: python

This is my situation; I am attempting to make a python program that takes user input and detects any consonants ('B, C, D, F, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, P, Q, R, S, T, V, X, Z') in the string of the user input, then replaces said letters with a "?" symbol. Along with print the original word and the number of found consonants.

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
Please enter a word or zzz to quit: Dramatics
The original word is: dramatics
The word without consonants is: ??a?a?i??
The number of consonants in the word are: 6
```

**MY CODE:**

```
 C =  input("Enter A Word (CAPITALS ONLY):")
 S = str(C)
 QUESTIONMARK = str("?")
 chars = str('B, C, D, F, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, P, Q, R, S, T, V, X, Z')
 if any((C in chars) for C in S):
     FINAL = str.replace(QUESTIONMARK,str(S),chars)
     print(FINAL)
 else:
     print('Not Found')
```

**MY OUTPUT:**

> ***This is what is returned on WING Pro running Python 3.7:***
>
> ```
>  Enter A Word (CAPITALS ONLY):HELLO
>  ?
> ```
>
> If there are any solutions to this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can that word have other characters than consonants and vowels?

Comment: It has to be able to use only consonants. I commented my findings on your answer below if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get `FINAL`, this will replace every element that is not a vowel with "?":

```
FINAL = ''.join(e if e in "AEIOU" else "?" for e in S)
```

You can make some improvements in your code. If you are using Python 3, `input` returns a string so you don't need to cast, you can define `S` directly as follows:

```py
S = input("Enter A Word (CAPITALS ONLY):")
QUESTIONMARK = "?"
CONSONANTS = 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXZ'

if any((C in CONSONANTS) for C in S):
    FINAL = ''.join(e if e in "AEIOU" else "?" for e in S)
    number_of_consonants = sum(1 for c in S if c in CONSONANTS)
    print(FINAL)
else:
    print('Not Found')

print(f'The original word is: {S}')
print(f'The word without consonants is: {FINAL}')
print(f'The number of consonants in the word are: {number_of_consonants}')
```

If you need to count the number of consonants, you can use the following

```py
CONSONANTS = 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXZ'
number_of_consonants = sum(1 for c in S if c in CONSONANTS)
```

Comment: And is there any way that this can determine the number of consonants in the word?

Comment: @PryroTech, what do you mean? do you need a variable that holds the number of consonants?

Comment: That would be correct. As you can see in the "Example Output" code above, it also counts the number of consonants in the word (The number of consonants in the word are: 6)

Comment: @PryroTech, I updated my answer. I hope this is doing what you want now, and notice that I am using a Python feature called f-strings introduced in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with a list comprehension:

```
vowels='aeiou'
word = input('Please enter a word or zzz to quit: ')
print('The original word is: '+word.lower())
masked = ''.join([l if l.lower() in vowels else '?' for l in word])
print('The word without consonants is: '+masked)
print('The number of consonants in the word are: '+str(masked.count('?')))
```

output:

```
Please enter a word or zzz to quit: Dramatics
The original word is: dramatics
The word without consonants is: ??a?a?i??
The number of consonants in the word are: 6
```